# User.id is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs

I'm building a website where users can register, but when registration is complete nothing happens, its supposed to enter the site.

I have tested it with console.log and found out that my `user.id` is undefined.

this is my register on the server side:

```
const handleRegister = (req, res, db, bcrypt) => {
    const { email, name, password } = req.body;
    if (!email || !name || !password) {
        return res.status(400).json('incorrect form submission');
    }
    const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password);
    db.transaction(trx => {
        trx.insert({
            hash: hash,
            email: email
        })
        .into('login')
        .returning('email')
        .then(loginEmail => {
            console.log(email)
            return trx('users')
            .returning('*')
            .insert({
                email: email,
                name: name,
                joined: new Date()
            })
            .then(user => {
            res.json(user[0]);
            })
        })
        .then(trx.commit)
        .catch(trx.rollback)
    })

    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('unable to register ' + err))

}module.exports = {
handleRegister: handleRegister
};
```

and this is my register on the frontend:

```
import React from 'react';

class Register extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            email: '',
            password: ''
        }
    }

    onNameChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({name: event.target.value})
    }

    onEmailChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({email: event.target.value})
    }

    onPasswordChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({password: event.target.value})
    }

    onSubmitSignIn = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/register', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name: this.state.name,
                email: this.state.email,
                password: this.state.password   
            })
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(user => {
         console.log(user.id);
         if (user.id) {
            console.log(user, user.id);
            this.props.loadUser(user)
            this.props.onRouteChange('home');
        }console.log(user.id);
      })
    }
```

It is on the frontend I have set the console.log and it never enters the if statement.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you check what your code is returning when you are doing res.json(user[0]) ?

Comment: try console.logging on server side before line res.json(user[0]); What is printed then?

Comment: console.log(user) on the server gives me the id of the new user like this [40]

Comment: A temporary fix could be to enter the signin page instead of home

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mongodb the id field is defined as _id

Comment: I'm using MySQL